# ui-view for 1 module duplicating content from another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

https://plnkr.co/edit/n2RANdhtRYIGQURVIElY?p=preview

#### Expected

After <kbd>login</kbd>, when you click <kbd>Count</kbd> the red number should change in the Tags list and match the number in the Tickers list, but nothing should happen in the Feed list.

#### Results

After <kbd>login</kbd>, clicking <kbd>Count</kbd> in the Tickers list, the red number appears in both the Tags list and Feed list.

[image]

---

**Full plnkr code**

```
var tickers = angular.module('tickers', ['ui.router'])

tickers.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tickers = {
    name: 'tickers',
    url: '/tickers',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: '<p></p>'
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tickers);
  
})

tickers.component('tickersModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Tickers init', $state.params)

    $scope.counter = 0;
    
    $scope.increase = function() {
      $scope.counter++;
      $state.go('tags', { counter: $scope.counter }).then(function() {
      });
    }
  }
})



var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])

tags.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tags = {
    name: 'tags',
    url: '/tags',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    params: {
      counter: 0
    },
    template: '<p class="counter">{{ counter }}</p>',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('tags state object', $state)
      $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
    }
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tags);
  
})

tags.component('tagsModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tags-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    
  }
})


var feed = angular.module('feed', ['ui.router'])

feed.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const feed = {
    name: 'feed',
    url: '/feed',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: '<em>Feed items go here.</em>'
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(feed);
  
})

feed.component('feedModule', {
  templateUrl: 'feed-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Feed init', $state.params)

  }
})


var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'tickers', 'tags', 'feed']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    const login = {
      name: 'login',
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'l',
      controller: function($state) {
        this.login = function() {
          $state.go('dashboard', {})
        }
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
      name: 'dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
      controller: function($state) {
        console.log('Dashboard state init', $state)
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
        .state(login)
        .state(dashboard);

})
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state',
function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
            // console.log(' ')
            // console.log('toState', toState)
            // console.log('toParams', toParams)
            // console.log('fromState', fromState)
            // console.log('fromParams', fromParams)
            // console.log('options', options)
        });
}]);
```

The tags-module-template.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h2>Tags list</h2>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The feed-module-template.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h2>Feed list</h2>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The dashboard.html which is associated with the dashboard state in the routerApp module. Contains all 3 components:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Dashboard</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <tickers-module></tickers-module>
  <tags-module></tags-module>
  <feed-module></feed-module>
</div>
```

Tags module, state config and component code:

```
var tags = angular.module('tags', ['ui.router'])

tags.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const tags = {
    name: 'tags',
    url: '/tags',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    params: {
      counter: 0
    },
    template: '<p class="counter">{{ counter }}</p>',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      console.log('tags state object', $state)
      $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
    }
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(tags);
  
})

tags.component('tagsModule', {
  templateUrl: 'tags-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    
  }
})
```

Feed module, state config and component code

```
var feed = angular.module('feed', ['ui.router'])

feed.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const feed = {
    name: 'feed',
    url: '/feed',
    parent: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: '<em>Feed items go here.</em>'
  }
  
  $stateProvider
    .state(feed);
  
})

feed.component('feedModule', {
  templateUrl: 'feed-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Feed init', $state.params)

  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `tags` and `feed` to your state, just as `dashboard` and `login` (with name, templateUrl, and different controlers) ? Then, doing `ui-view="tags"` and `ui-view="feed"` or something similar ?

Comment: I tried `ui-view="tags"` at some point and it didn't work, but I want these modules separated out. The end goal is that changing something in one module won't necessarily cause another module to refresh / re-init.

Comment: That's weird. Usually `ui-view` without a value refers to `index.html`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/5A5YFEWZ7ZTzRJloxgka?p=preview

I was finally able to fix this problem by using named views inside of the **Tags $state object**.

```
const tags = {
  name: 'tags',
  url: '/tags',
  parent: 'dashboard',
  params: {
    counter: 0
  },
  views: {
    'default' : { template: '<p>Hi this is Tags</p>' },
    'title' : {
      template: '<p>Tags Title! {{ number }}</p>',
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.number = Math.random();
      }
    },
    'counter': {
      template: '<p class="counter">Counter:{{ counter }}</p>',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        console.log('tags state object', $state);
        $scope.counter = $state.params.counter;
      }
    }
  }
}

$stateProvider.state(tags);
```

Now with these named views, I can use `ui-view` with a specific name to target the location of the updating counter variable coming in from the tickers.component.

The params object is still associated with the `tags` state, so the incoming state.go from tickers will send in the parameter, however a named sub view of tags will now contain the counter. And it won't bleed out into the un-named or named ui-view in the feed.component.

**The tags template html:**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h2>Tags list</h2>
  <div ui-view="default"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Tags title here:
      <div ui-view="title"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
      Tags counter here:
      <div ui-view="counter"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

tickers.component still targets the `tags` state and passes the counter variable in.

```
$scope.increase = function() {
  $scope.counter++;
  $state.go('tags', { counter: $scope.counter });
}
```

Comment: As long as you use `ui-view="title"` and `ui-view="counter"` only in `tags-module` template, this will work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/h5hT9g4aAUR1v3XHmMeJ?p=preview) that has the desired functionality.

Before going into my solution, let's go through yours.

The reason why it worked the way you described was because `ui-router` is doing what is suppose to do :).

Even though you have tried to separate loading of the templates into separate modules, that didn't go as you've planned. As soon as the `dashboard` state was loaded, all your components were loaded as well.
The reason why both `tags-module` and `feed-module` were updated at the same time is because their respective templates had `ui-view` in them. So when you click the button and execute `$state.go("tags"...`, you have basically loaded the `tags` state template in every component with `ui-view` attribute in it.

Solution that I've provided uses `$rootScope.$emit` and `$rootScope.$on` to send out dand receive data. I must say that you should **avoid using $rootScope as much as you can**, but for the sake brevity I used it here (shame on me) and because there was no parent-child relationships here to just use `$scope`. Other possible solutions:

- Restructure your app so that your components could talk to each other.
- Use either your own or third party pub sub library so your components can talk to each other.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, using events was how our app was 6 months ago. We're trying to accomplish this using only $state and views. Your answer works, if there are no other $state/view based answers soon I'll check your solution. But will keep trying to find a $state way.

Comment: Found a solution! Posting now and you can review.